# Read & split multiple column text file into arrays

Tags: java, arrays, split, java.util.scanner, readfile

For a project I'm working on a fairly big animal dataset with up to 14 parameters of data. I was able to read it in and display it as strings using this:

```
public static void readIn(String file) throws IOException {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(file));
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        String[] columns = scanner.nextLine().split("/t");
        String data = columns[columns.length-1];
        System.out.println(data);
    }
}
```

and displaying something like this:

```
04:00:01    0.11    0.04    -0.1    1047470 977.91  91.75
04:00:01    0.32    -0.03   -0.07   1047505 977.34  92.91
04:00:01    0.49    -0.03   -0.08   1047493 978.66  92.17
```

But I'm currently having trouble trying to split each column into separate arrays so that I can process the data (e.g. calculating means). Any idea of how I can do this? Any help would be much appreciated.

**Edit:** thanks, I've found out a solution that works and also lets me choose which channel it reads specifically. I've also decided to store the data as arrays within the class, here's what I have now:

```
public static void readChannel(String file, int channel) throws IOException 
{
    List<Double> dataArr = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(file));
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        String[] columns = scanner.nextLine().split("\t");

        for (int i = channel; i < columns.length; i+=(columns.length-channel)) {
            dataArr.add(Double.parseDouble(columns[i]));
            dataArr.toArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the file is tab delimitted, then you need `\t` instead of `/t`, which is likely why it's not working as expected?

Comment: After you have processed your file, where and how are you storing the data? In a matrix (like `String[][]`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store all rows in an ArrayList and then create arrays for each column and store values in them. Sample code:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(file));
ArrayList<String> animalData = new ArrayList<String>();
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    String[] columns = scanner.nextLine().split("/t");
    String data = columns[columns.length-1];
    animalData.add(data);
    System.out.println(data);
}

int size = animalData.size();
String[] arr1 = new String[size]; String[] arr2 = new String[size]; 
String[] arr3 = new String[size]; String[] arr4 = new String[size];
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    String[] temp = animalData.get(i).split("\t");
    arr1[i] = temp[0];
    arr2[i] = temp[1];
    arr3[i] = temp[2];
    arr4[i] = temp[3];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should split your problem in 2:

1. File reading:

   Your program read each line and save it inside a instance of a class defined by you:

   ```
   public class MyData {
       private String time;
       private double percent;
       //... and so on
   }
   public MyData readLine( String line ) {
       String[] columns = line.split("\t");
       MyData md = new MyData();
       md.setTime( columns[ 0 ] );
       md.setPercent( Double.parseDouble(columns[ 1 ]) );
   }
   public void readFile( File file ) {
       Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
       List<MyData> myList = new ArrayList<>();
       while (scanner.hasNext()) {
           MyData md = readLine( scanner.nextLine() );
           myList.add( md );
       }
   }
   ```
2. Data processing:

   After you processed your file, you can create the method you need to process the data:

   ```
   int sum = 0;
   for ( MyData md : myList ) {
       sum = sum + md.getValue();
   }
   ```

I hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

Following snippet will list down all values for a given index

```
public static void readIn(String file) throws Exception {

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(file));
  final Map<Integer,List<String>> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
  while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    String[] columns = scanner.nextLine().split("/t");
    for(int i=0;i<columns.length;i++){
      resultMap.computeIfAbsent(i, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(columns[i]);
    }
  }   resultMap.keySet().forEach(index -> System.out.println(resultMap.get(index).toString()));}
```